# Postgres float column sum delta. Update schema or use cast?

Tags: sql, postgresql, casting, schema

It's not a new thing to discuss, but I just want you opinion.
What is a better solution in this case:

there is a column with float values:

```
Column   | Type | Collation | Nullable |                     
----------------------------------------
work_res | real |           | not null |
```

When I calculate `sum` over the whole table it gives one value, let's assume 100.2123

```
select sum(work_res) from work_data
>> 100.2123
```

But when I work on the same data and group first and after do `sum`, then sum is 100.9124

```
select sum(gd.work_res)
from (
    select type, sum(work_res) as work_res
    from work_data
    group by type
  ) as gd

>> 100.9124
```

- `type` column is just for example as a column to group by

So the problem is round here. If I will use cast to `double precision` in the sum function, then numbers are identical.

```
select sum(cast(work_res  as double precision)) from work_data
>> 100.9124
```

Can you please advise what is better solution for me:

- Use casting each time
- Update the schema

Values in the column can be in range (0, 1].
For example, it can be: 0.(3), 1, 0.5, 0.(1) and so on

I think in both cases I will still see a small delta. Right?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you want a solution (update the schema) or a work around (casting each time) ?

Comment: you should use decimal and efine the precision you need, float have fractals by nature